# Python Regex Mark-Up

Tags: python, regex

Hi guys having trouble with a particular problem.
I am using python's regex to alter the markup source to output html format.

markup source:

```
[ 
# sometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometext.  #

# sometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometext
sometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometext. #
]


[
hello i am a normal paragraph.
]
```

desired output:

```
<ol> 
<li> sometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometext.  </li>

<li> sometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometext
sometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometext. </li>
</ol>

<p>
hello i am a normal paragraph.
</p>
```

Comment: How is the code supposed to know whether to put the text in a list or a paragraph?

Comment: The presence of a '#' within the square brackets.. i guess, not entirely sure.

Comment: So what exactly is your problem, and what solutions have you tried?

Comment: I need to distinguish between a [text] and a [#list#]
sub(r'\#(.*?)\#', '<li>\g<1></li>', data) partially works (works for the first line of sometext, not the second.

Comment: just an idea: http://www.regex101.com/r/iG0qF0

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
with open('mk.txt') as f:
    with open('newmk.txt','w+') as g:
        text = f.read()
        SquareGroups = re.findall(r'\[(?:.|\n)+?\]',text)
        for group in SquareGroups:
            if '#' in group: #must be ol
                group = group.replace('[','<ol>')
                group = group.replace(']','</ol>')
                group = re.sub('#(?= ?\w)','<li>',group)
                group = re.sub('(?<=[\w ])#','</li>',group)
            else:
                group = group.replace('[','<p>')
                group = group.replace(']','</p>')
            g.write(group)
            g.write('\n') #optional, just makes the output look 'nicer'
```

Transforms your input in `mk.txt` into the following text in `newmk.txt`:

```
<ol>
<li> sometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometext.  </li>

<li> sometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometext
sometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometext. </li>
</ol>
<p>
hello i am a normal paragraph.
</p>
```